# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'EthereumRPC\EthereumRPC' not found

Tags: php, class, autoload

I've been playing with this for hours now, finding all kind of autoloaders but I can't figure it out:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    //class directories
    $directorys = array(
        'EthereumRPC/',
        'EthereumRPC/API/',
        'EthereumRPC/API/Personal/',
        'EthereumRPC/Contracts/',
        'EthereumRPC/Contracts/ABI/',
        'EthereumRPC/Exception/',
        'EthereumRPC/Response/',
        'ERC20/',
        'ERC20/data/',
        'ERC20/Exception/'
    );

    //for each directory
    foreach($directorys as $directory)
    {
        //see if the file exsists
        if(file_exists($directory.$class_name . '.php'))
        {
            require_once($directory.$class_name . '.php');
            //only require the class once, so quit after to save effort (if you got more, then name them something else 
            return;
        }            
    }
}

use EthereumRPC\EthereumRPC;
use ERC20\ERC20;
```

I load every directory that contains classes but I still end up with the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'EthereumRPC\EthereumRPC' not found in /home/sewicumg/public_html/contenthourlies.com/wp-content/themes/seoexp/account_client.php:62

The instruction file said to only include the two lines at the bottom but that definitely didn't work.

Am I missing something?

Here is the code that uses the classes:

```
$geth = new EthereumRPC('127.0.0.1', 8545);
$erc20 = new ERC20($geth);
```

All those EthereumRPC and ERC20 folders are in the same directory as the php file that this code is in.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Your not mutating the path to namespace e.g / to \ - What lib are you using?

Comment: I'm using this one: https://github.com/furqansiddiqui/erc20-php

Comment: ok, so why you not using composer?

Comment: When I change the slashes to backslashes (or vice versa) I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'EthereumRPC' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: Because I'm at a shared host / cpanel installation.

Comment: ^^ You need to escape the slash.. Install it locally, then just upload..

Comment: Why are the use statements at the bottom?  You should also look into PSR4 auto loading.  You can use mine https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Autoloader its also available on composer.

Comment: How do I escape the slash? I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: I put the use statements temporarily at the bottom to see if it would make a difference.

Comment: `str_replace('\\', '/', $class_name);` but your autoloader wont handle this `EthereumRPC\Contracts\ABI\SHA3` it would be trying to match `EthereumRPC/EthereumRPC\Contracts\ABI\SHA3.php` which it wont find.

Comment: I uploaded all the folders already, same directory as the php file that the code is in.

Comment: How about I put all those php files in the same folder as account_client.php, and then instead of new EthereumRPC() put it like: new EthereumRPC.php() or something like that?

Comment: Isn't there an easy way to load a library using a shared hosting that doesn't come with a command line / shell type of thing?

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix, how can I use your autoloader, where in the file do I have to enter autoloader.php?